# Chose which function to run in script

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make it so that the user chooses which function to run using if.

```
import os
import csv
import collections
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import time
import string
import re
import glob, os

folder_path = 'C:/ProgramData/WebPort/system/tags'
folder2_path = 'C:/ProgramData/WebPort/system'
search2_str = '"Prefix"'

print("Choices:\n 1 - Read from CSV\n 2 - Read from WPP")
x = input("Please enter your choice:\n")
 
x = int(x)
 
if x == 1:
    csv_file_list = glob.glob(folder_path + '/*.csv')
with open("csv.txt", 'w') as wf:
    for file in csv_file_list:
        print(glob.glob(folder_path + '/*.csv'))
        with open(file) as rf:
            for line in rf:
                if line.strip(): # if line is not empty
                    if not line.endswith("\n"):
                        line+="\n"
                    wf.write(line)
    print('Reading from .csv')

elif x == 2:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder2_path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".wpp"):
             print(os.path.join(root, file))

        with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as fr, open ("wpp.txt",'a',  encoding='utf-8') as fw:
            for i,line in enumerate(fr):
                if line.find(search2_str) != -1: 
                    fw.write(line)
    print('Reading from .wpp')

else:
    print('wrong choice')
```

Getting Invalid syntax in line 34 using this.

Comment: Can you post the full error so we don't need to count lines?

Comment: Python is a whitespace-sensitive language based on indentations. Your `elif` is not indented after any `if` (because the `with` makes it a new block)

Comment: So how is the best way to to this? What should i serach/read up on?

Comment: Basic Python syntax? It seems like you just need to indent that `with` block to be under the `if`... That would solve the error and probably what you meant for

Comment: What i am trying to do is a function that i can call using a push button in qt designer. but its a long way there :D

Comment: Was it fixed by indenting the `with`?